# StripeSignatureVerificationError: No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload

Tags: stripe-payments, webhooks

```
router.post(
  "/",
  bodyParser.raw({ type: "application/json" }),
  async (req, res) => {
    // Retrieve the event by verifying the signature using the raw body and secret.
    let event;
    const signature = req.headers["stripe-signature"]
    const endPointSecret = "whsec_***"
    console.log(signature)
    console.log(req.body)
    try {
      event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(
        req.body,
        signature,
        endPointSecret
      );
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return res.sendStatus(400);
    }
    // Extract the object from the event.
    const dataObject = event.data.object;
    console.log(dataObject)
    res.sendStatus(200)
  }
);
```

```
I am testing Webhook on localhost by listening and forwarding event from Stripe CLI to localhost. And I am using endpoint secret (from stripe cli provided after "stripe listen" command).
 Still having signature verification error!!
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have any other `bodyParser` middleware set up? You need to make sure your webhook route only uses the raw body parser, as per this example: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node/blob/master/examples/webhook-signing/node-express/express.js#L10-L17

Comment: app.use((req, res, next) => {
    if (req.originalUrl === '/stripe-webhook') {
      next();
    } else {
      express.json()(req , res , next)
    }
  });

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the right webhook secret key.

You may have defined that key just for the online webhook endpoint, and not for  local usage. Set it up in your local env vars as instance.